# How to get the document id of the document on which user clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**JS:**

```
function getDataOfBus() {
   var dates = document.getElementById('departure-date').value.toString();
   var fromd = document.getElementById('from-dest').value.toString()
   var tod = document.getElementById('to-dest').value.toString()
   console.log(dates + " -" + fromd + " -" + tod)

   db.collection('Buses').where("DepartureDate", "==", dates).where("To", "==", tod).
   where("From", "==", fromd).get().then((snapshot) => {
      let html = '';
      snapshot.forEach((busDatas) => {
         busData = busDatas.data()
         console.log(busData.id)
         html += `
           <div class="single-room-area d-flex align-items-center mb-50 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="100ms" id="prince">
            <div class="room-thumbnail">
                <img src="${busData.ImageLink}" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="room-content">
                <h2><a href="javascript:setImage();">${busData.TourName}</h2>
                <h6>${busData.From} to ${busData.To}</h6>
                <h4>₹ ${busData.SeatPrice} </h4>
                <div class="room-feature">
                    <h6>Boarding Point  <span>${busData.BoardingTime}</span></h6>
                    <h6>Dropping Point <span>${busData.DroppingTime}</span></h6>
                    <h6>Seats Left <span>${busData.SeatsLeft}</span></h6>
                    <h6>Total Time <span>${busData.TotalTime}</span></h6>
                    <h6>Departure Date <span>${busData.DepartureDate}</span></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>
         `

         document.getElementById('bus-container-dynamic').innerHTML = html;
      }) // End foreach
   }) // End then

}

function setImage() {

}
```

I have performed the above code to display the documents from the cloud Firestore. But i am not getting how to get that document id of that document on which the user clicks and use that document id in `setImage()` function?

Comment: You haven't it in busData.id?

Comment: i am getting undefined and i want on click on the TourName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `busData = busDatas.data()` you are assigning the object returned by the `data()` method to the `busData` variable, but this object does not contain the doc ID.

You should either use another variable to hold this value or assign the document ID to this `busData` object. The following (implementing the second option) should do the trick:

```
snapshot.forEach((busDatas) => {

    var busData = busDatas.data()
    busData.docId = busDatas.id
    //...

    <h2><a href="javascript:setImage('${busData.docId}');">${busData.TourName}</h2>
    //...

});
```

---

`busDatas` (with an s) is a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) and you use its [`id`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#id) property.

---

You could also use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), as follows:

```
var busData = { docId: busDatas.id, ...busDatas.data() }
```

Comment: i am getting error from where you have called this function setImage() that   VM1498:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: JYD99NsjS1VYCvZbG8Uo is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:10    (where JYD99NsjS1VYCvZbG8Uo is the document id) int this line <h2><a href="javascript:setImage('${busData.docId}');">${busData.TourName}</h2>

Comment: See the update, I forgot to add single quotes around `${busData.docId}`. It was then considered as a variable name instead of a string value.